# Credentials in Streamsets

Tags: streamsets

In my current project I'm working with StreamSets and I would like to use Hashicorp Vault as my credentials store, however I'm not able to use `credential:get()` function wherever I want to. E.g. in Shared Access Key in Azure IoT Hub Producer block. I know that I could use Runtime Properties but I don't think it solves my problem.
Am I missing something or I can use `credential:get()` only in fields marked with a key icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `credential:get()` in fields marked with a key icon. This is by design, to minimize the chance of leaking credentials. For example, if `credential:get()` was allowed in URL parameters, a pipeline designer could send a request to a web server under their control to discover the credential. It may make sense to allow **Shared Access Key** to receive credentials. Please file an issue at https://issues.streamsets.com with your enhancement request.